# Converting each rows from a table to a Column - SQl

Tags: sql

```
| Fullname  | department |code               |
| --------  | -----------|-------------------|
| John Doe  | Marketing  |AB.marketing.1240  | 
| John Doe  | sales      |AB.sales.30        |
| John Doe  | service    |AB.service.2000    |
| John Doe  | customer   |AB.customer.11023  |
```

I have a table in above format with name and department details. I am looking for a way convert all the rows under department to a separate columns so that the table will look like the below table. For each fullName, I am expecting to extract marketing, sales,service etc in a single row as below.

```
| Fullname  | Marketing         |sales              |service         |customer |
| --------  | ----------------- |-------------------|----------------|-----------|
| John Doe  | AB.marketing.1240 |AB.sales.30        |AB.service.2000 | AB.customer.11023|
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: There are, however, countless examples of how to do this in many dialects; what were wrong with those many examples?

Comment: to add to @Larnu 's comment  this is called [pivotting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+pivot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
    select Fullname,
     max(case when department='Marketing' then code end) as Marketing,
     max(case when department='sales' then code end)  as sales,
     max(case when department='service' then code end) as service,
    max(case when department='customer' then code end) as customer
  from table_name group by Fullname
```

Comment: A `CASE` expression requires an `END`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server then you can use `PIVOT`

Schema and insert statements:

```
 CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS(Fullname VARCHAR(50), department VARCHAR(50), code VARCHAR(50));

 INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES('John Doe','Marketing','AB.marketing.1240');

 INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES('John Doe','sales','AB.sales.30');

 INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES('John Doe','service','AB.service.2000');

 INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES('John Doe','customer','AB.customer.11023');
```

Query:

```
 select *
 from DEPARTMENTS
 pivot
 (
   max(code) for department in ([Marketing],[sales],[service],[customer])
 ) as pvt
```

Output:

| Fullname | Marketing | sales | service | customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | AB.marketing.1240 | AB.sales.30 | AB.service.2000 | AB.customer.11023 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8544a69e88169127c77d445ffbf50fdc)*

If you are using oracle then:

Query:

```
 select *
 from DEPARTMENTS
 pivot
 (
   max(code) for department in ('Marketing','sales','service','customer')
 )  pvt
```

Output:

| FULLNAME | 'Marketing' | 'sales' | 'service' | 'customer' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | AB.marketing.1240 | AB.sales.30 | AB.service.2000 | AB.customer.11023 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9067c2f56864da900c7dadc2d53a48e3)*